# Need help solving this ODE of first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to determine the general solution of

$$ y'= y+ \frac{ \sin(t)}{y} $$

with what method can I solve this ?
Appreciate any help!

Comment: Hint: This is a case of Bernoulli's differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is a so-called Bernoulli equation, which is an ODE of the form:
$$y'+p(t) y=q(t) y^{n}$$
Notice that you recover your equation by setting $p(t)=-1$, $q(t)=\sin(t)$ and $n=-1$.

A standard way to solve these equations is presented here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliDifferentialEquation.html